# Rails 4.2 OR scope using includes/joins

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql, ruby-on-rails-4, activerecord, rails-postgresql

Given a `List` model with relationships:

```
has_many :list_group_memberships, dependent: :destroy
has_many :groups, through: :list_group_memberships
has_many :users, -> { unscope(:order).uniq }, through: :groups, source: :users
```

I have a scope that needs to work like this:

```
includes(:users).where(recipient: user, secret: false).or(where(users: { id: user }))
```

`Recipient` and `secret` are attributes on the `List` model.

I'm using the [where-or](https://github.com/Eric-Guo/where-or) gem (a backport of Rails 5 AR `or` scope).

The error received is:

```
ArgumentError: Relation passed to #or must be structurally compatible
```

Is this sort of query possible using Rails' syntax?

Comment: Show all the model relationships.

Answer (score 0):

I am presuming that user is a variable.

```
includes(:users).where("(recipient = ? AND secret = ?) OR users.id = ?", user, false, user)
```

Comment: Sorry I should have mentioned that the `has_many :users` relationship is a double `through`, so it's not as easy as using the SQL above, and why I needed to use Rails syntax rather than raw SQL :(